Python project to exe, , tagged as virus
I can't find a solution to what seems like a simple problem. I prepared an educational game in python. I want to distribute it to people who are inexperienced with computers, and PyInstaller (6.8.0) seemed the right solution for me. But the exe file obtained for Windows....is blocked as a malware by antivirus software. (On VirusTotal it results positive to 5, 6 AV on the total) If I move it from "quarantine" it works perfectly, but I can't ask this of users.
I tried an older version version of PyInst., it results the same. I looked for alternative solutions, like Py2exe (I found instructions too brief) or cx_Freeze (but it requires that the user install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package?),but I didn't find the solution yet. Can anyone help me, please?

That's a problem with your virus scanner. Report to its author -- we can't help here.

you have the people shipping malware using pyinstaller to thank for that .... at this point you could just ship the interpreter alongside python .py files with a .bat script that runs the application (doing the equivalent of python myscript.py in a cmd), and forget about making a .exe .... for obfuscation some people would use cython to package their files as .pyd files which seems to prevent non-programmers from looking into the code.

upload your software to pypi and make a .bat file that downloads the module (if it hasn't already) and runs it.  The added benefit of this method is that the .bat file will be tiny, it can check for updates, and your users are non-the-wiser about what's actually going on. You can follow this guide from RealPython on how to package your software.

@ Charles Duffy - my .exe is marked as malware by both AVG and Avira Antivir
